# keycloak to secure multiple web application

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak as an authentication service for my web application.
I have 2 applications installed as follows.

1. https://example.com.         => app1
2. https://example.com/new.     => app2

I want to restrict users to the application like user1 should only be allowed for app1 and user2 should only be allowed for app2.

I have created 2 resources (Authorization -> Resources) and created a user-based policy for each Resource but still, all users can log in to all applications.

I even tried 2 user policy for one Resource

1. One will explicitly deny a user to the Resource
   2, One will explicitly allow a user to the same Resource

But still, nothing is worked. Can someone please help me?